# Switching from .html to .php made my custom font dissappear

Tags: php, html, css, fonts

I am wanting to know why when I switched my .html to a .php file my css stopped working and my font no longer works. I have not been able to find any answers on this either.

I had this font throughout the entire forum and for some reason the font stopped working when I added php to the script after getting ready to start php.

```
<style type="text/css">
@font-face { font-family: BillyReg; src: url('fonts/Billy-Regular.TTF'); } 
html, body, form, fieldset, table, tr, td, img{
    font-family: BillyReg;
}


...style is closed later on....
```

I looked for solutions and everyone said to do what was already done.

Adding the php tags at the top of the page is having the page and its fonts react in strange ways the tables will go from center to left, the fonts will go from teal to black and similar behaviors, this is happening in microsoft expression 4, not when it renders the page other than losing the actual font type im using.

Comment: Is the PHP in the same folder as the HTML was? Is the `fonts` folder a subdirectory of that folder?

Comment: Have you try to see what happen into browser console? Maybe you get a 404.....

Comment: The php and html files are in the same folders, and are uploaded as well to the same folders.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
    @font-face { font-family: BillyReg; src: url('/fonts/Billy-Regular.TTF'); }
```

or

```
    @font-face { font-family: BillyReg; src: url('./fonts/Billy-Regular.TTF'); }
```

Comment: this does not work.